# Php: Hypertext Preprocessor - $_GET, $_POST error

Tags: php, html, error-handling

```
<?php
              echo "<br>";
(line 106)    echo $_GET["nume"] . "<br>";
(line 107)    echo "{$_GET["parola"]} <br>";
(line 108)    echo "Bine ai venit {$_GET["nume"]}";
              echo "<br>";

    $element = "fruct/e";
    $pret = "4.25";
    $quantity = $_POST["nume1"];
    $total = null;
    $total = $quantity * $pret;

    echo "Tu ai cumparat {$quantity} {$element} <br>";
    echo "Totalul tau este de \${$total}.";
?>

    <form action="index.php" method="get"> 

    <label name="nume">Numele utilizatorului:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="nume" placeholder="Introduceti aici numele">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label name="parola">Parola utilizatorului:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="parola" placeholder="Introduceti aici parola">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Logheaza-te"></input>

    </form>


    <form action="index.php" method="post">

    <label>Cantitate</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="nume1" placeholder="Introduceti aici numarul">
    <input type="submit" value="Trimite">

    </form>
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "nume" in
> C:\Users\avdel\OneDrive\Desktop\Html+Css\Site\Arhiva siteuri
> 3\index.php on line 106
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "parola" in
> C:\Users\avdel\OneDrive\Desktop\Html+Css\Site\Arhiva siteuri
> 3\index.php on line 107
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "nume" in
> C:\Users\avdel\OneDrive\Desktop\Html+Css\Site\Arhiva siteuri
> 3\index.php on line 108

I want my code to function in order to not get that error.

Comment: Duplicate of: ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Comment: Basically: These warnings occur because your PHP code is trying to read values from $_GET and $_POST when the page first loads, but those values will only exist in a subsequent request, after one of the forms has been submitted.
You need to check if these fields actually exist before trying to use them. You can check each one with `isset()`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: For example: `if (isset($_GET["nume"], $_GET["parole"])) { echo "<br>"; echo $_GET["nume"] . "<br>"; echo "{$_GET["parola"]} <br>"; echo "Bine ai venit {$_GET["nume"]}"; echo "<br>"; }`

Comment: And then: `if (isset($_POST["nume1"])) { $element = "fruct/e";  $pret = "4.25";  $quantity = $_POST["nume1"]; $total = null; $total = $quantity * $pret; echo "Tu ai cumparat {$quantity} {$element} <br>"; echo "Totalul tau este de \${$total}."; }`